# GDB incomplete type when having C++ virtual function

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, virtual

I have just noticed something weird, when I add the "virtual keyword" in my class (any function except the constructor), I can't display the content of my object in GDB. GDB says "incomplete type"

Here is the code :

//////////////// reco.h /////////////

```
#ifndef RECO_H
#define RECO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class reco {
    public:
        reco(float weight);
        ~reco(void);

        float getWeight();

    private:
        float weight;
};

#endif
```

///////////////// reco.cpp /////////////

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "reco.h"

using namespace std;

reco::reco(float weight) {
    weight = weight;
}

reco::~reco(void) {
    cout << "destructor reco" << endl;
}

float reco::getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
```

////////////// main.cpp /////////////

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "reco.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {
    reco* s = new reco(5.0);
    cout << s->getWeight() << endl;

    delete s;

    return 0;
}
```

Then with GDB :

```
gdb main.exe
breakpoint main.cpp:11 <---- (cout)
run
print *s
$1 = { weight = 5 }
```

And then, if I make one of the functions "virtual", and I retry to print my `*s` pointer with GDB, it says: 
"incomplete type"

It looks like there is something happening with the VTABLE, as if the "virtual" keyword was hiding the implementation of my Reco class. I know that the compiler does late binding and then, the VTABLE lookup is done at runtime, but the program is already running while GDB is debugging it, right ?

The "set print vtbl" setting in "on".

If I use `ptype s`, I get the `<incomplete type>` message again.

If I examine the address with `x/540f80`, it says "cannot access memory"

I don't know why just adding this keyword makes my object's type incomplete ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

One last thing that I notice :

WITH VIRTUAL:

```
 reco.cpp -> g0 and main.cpp -> g = incomplete type
 reco.cpp -> g and main.cpp ->g = ok
```

WITHOUT VIRTUAL

```
 reco.cpp -> g0 and main.cpp -> g = ok
 reco.cpp -> g and main.cpp ->g = ok
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `reco.cpp -> g and main.cpp ->g = ok`

Assuming by `-> g` you mean that you compile `reco.cpp` with the `-g` flag, yes *do* that, and *don't* do this:

```
g++ -c -g0 reco.cpp
```

What you've discovered that is that GCC can optimize the amount on debug info it must emit *if* it knows that you have a [key method](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html).

Without `virtual`, there is no key method, and GCC must emit *redundant* debug info into *every* compilation unit. That makes your object files larger (it should have little or no effect on the final executable), but allows you to debug even when only some of your object files are compiled with debug info.

Comment: Sorry one more question to be clear:


Translation unit 1: reco.h and reco.cpp
Translation unit 2: main.cpp

Does it mean that without virtual, gcc produces debug info into unit 1 and unit 2, even if unit 1 is g0 ?

And then, does it mean that gcc (with virtual) produces debug info only in unit 1, as the key method is from reco.cpp ?